# PHP string echo the One thing before the end

Tags: php, string, url

my English is not good. sorry.

I want echo ***post_12345678*** from my URL sting:

**always want to echo the One thing before the end.**

```
<?php
$url_string = "https://localhost/categories/post_12345678/a25d48aff";
echo preg_replace('/[\^categories/].*?[\/]/' , '', $string );
?>
```

- a25d48aff and post_12345678 is Variable

Comment: You could simply use `parse_url` instead of regex.

Comment: You could use an HTTP URL parsing library that supports path normalization and path component handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), this task becomes much simpler. Just extract the value of the path key and access the second last key using [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`array_reverse`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).

```
<?php

$url_string = "https://localhost/categories/post_12345678/a25d48aff";

$str = trim(parse_url($url_string)['path'], '/');

echo array_reverse(explode("/", $str))[1];
```